# Tree help with identification

Tags: identification, trees

Can anyone tell me what type of tree this is please? ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjl6m.jpg)[image]

Comment: How big is the tree?

Comment: Big! About 20ft?

Comment: In which region/continent you found such tree?

Comment: Giacomo it is in Scotland :)

Answer (score 3):

I do not agree with @ColinBeckingham answer, but I agree with the family.

I think it is a Sorbus (whitebeam). Maybe the *Sorbus latifolia*, or a *Sorbus aria*. Sorbus has also hybrids.

Comment: I think you're right @Shona, you could check by feeling the leaves, Wikipedia says:

"The leaves are five to ten centimetres long and broad (rarely, up to 20 cm long and 12 cm broad), but, most typically, the leaves are approximately as broad as they are long. (Latifolia is the Latin word for 'broad-leaved'.) They are **green above, downy with greyish-white hairs beneath**, with six to ten small triangular teeth along each margin."

Comment: I shall take one of the leaves off and check when I can @MaxSpencer thank you!

Comment: @MaxSpencer .. the leaves are very soft underside, like velvet. The height of the tree us between 25 - 30 ft and it has no thorns

Answer (score 1):

Well it appears to be a Hawthorn or Crataegus, but which one is harder to say. If we look at Hawthorn leaves (say with a Google image search) the viewer will find there is a great variety of shapes, and this one fits with those which are less deeply lobed than most of them.

Given the size of the fruit and the size of the tree I would guess C. pinnatifida or Chinese Mountain Hawthorn. See if you can find thorns on the tree; if so, if there are just a few short thorns then this is a strong confirmation of C. pinnatifida, but if there are lots of brutally sharp thorns then that leans towards a more common Hawthorn.

Comment: Thanks for that Colin..its not my tree but my fathers so I'll have a look the.next time i'm along there 

Comment: I think it is a Sorbus. Check my answer. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Your tree is a Swedish Whitebeam, *Sorbus intermedia*, which is native to Sweden(!), and ranges from Denmark to Latvia and Poland, and more recently Scotland, Wales, England & Ireland. The illustration clearly shows the upper side of a typical characteristic leaf, which have hairlets on their undersides.

The Swedish Whitebeam is closely related to several other Whitebeam species, and can be distinguished from the Vosges Whitebeam/Mougeot's Whitebeam, *Sorbus mougeotii*, by the Swedish Whitebeam's characteristic leaf edges and generally more orangish fruit. The undersides of Whitebeam leaves typically are grayish-whitish with whitish veins, and gusts of wind can result in noteable sudden difference in the appearance of the trees, from which the name: 'Whitebeam'.

Swedish Whitebeams are fairly stout trees, typically grow to about 10m height, sometimes to 18+m, and have 70-200+cm  diameter trunks. They are also fairly hardy trees. Their fruit is used in baking, and to make jelly, though Swedish Whitebeams are often planted as ornamentals.